# Create a table from a query result with record fields in BiqQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

We have a set of tables with the data about users interactions online and we want to create a table with the scheme similar to [GA BigQuery Export Schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en) (this feature is not yet available in Russia).

I couldn't find the information on how to create a record field in BQ querying existing tables.

On the contrary, [it is written](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#creatingatable) that "This type is only available when using JSON source files."

Is there any workaround or this feature expected in a nearer future? Can I submit a feature request?

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only way to get nested and repeated records into BigQuery is loading JSON files. Once a query is run, all structure is flattened.

Feature request noted, hopefully BigQuery will support emitting nested records results!